# iOS Associated Domains not recognised on some devices

Tags: ios, webauthn, apple-app-site-associate, passkey, associated-domains

I have an app that uses webauthn (Passkey) login, and for that we have associated our app with our auth host domain. But sometimes, let's say on 1% of devices we get an error:

> Request cancelled after error: The operation couldn’t be completed. Application with identifier xxx.xxx.xxx is not associated with domain yyy.xxx.xxx.

And then auth doesn't work.

But on the same device checking the associated domain cache for the domain is fine. Is this an iOS bug?

Comment: the version of the application should be updated, after adding the universal link feature or adding the AASA file. if I got it correct.

Comment: Good point @MaziarSaadatfar .. I suppose this could trigger a refetch!

Comment: It registers on each installation or updates the app on the OS(iOS). and also it handles(check AASA) with versioning or new app installation. if it's okay, tell me know to Post the correct answer.

Comment: any update about the issue? @scrrr

Comment: it resolved itself.. but I believe that the versioning would have helped, but I haven't followed up on that topic yet.